# SwiftUI: How to make @StateObject ViewModel update when host View's state variable changes

Tags: swift, mvvm, core-data, swiftui, state

I have a View that displays a grid of images. The View has a `@StateObject` variable for its `ViewModel`, and a `@State` variable that stores the images.  (My image index is in Core Data, and the `@Query` property wrapper comes from [this post.](https://davedelong.com/blog/2021/04/03/core-data-and-swiftui/) TLDR: it stores the fetch results from Core Data, and when they change, it updates the `View` like a `@State` var.)

When the fetch results update, I need the `ViewModel` to know that this happened, so it can rebuild its index for use in my `ForEach`.  But I haven't found a way to hook those events together. I have verified that `indexAssets` is updating by manually refreshing the `ViewModel` on tap. What I need is for that refresh to happen automatically when `indexAssets` changes.

PhotoGridView.swift

```
struct PhotoGridView: View {
    @Query(.all) var indexAssets: QueryResults<IndexAsset>
    @StateObject var vm = PhotoGridViewModel()
    
    func updateVm() {
        vm.createIndex(indexAssets)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        return GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("\(indexAssets.count) assets")
                    Spacer()
                    TrashView()
                }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 4, leading: 16, bottom: 4, trailing: 16))
                ScrollView {
                    ForEach(vm.sortedKeys, id: \.self) { key in
                        let indexAssets = vm.index[key]
                        let date = indexAssets?.first?.creationDate
                        GridSectionView(titleDate:date, indexAssets:$vm.index[key], geoSize: geo.size)
                    }
                }
            }.onAppear {
                updateVm()
            }.onTapGesture {
                updateVm()
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: IndexAsset.self) { indexAsset in
                AssetDetailView(indexAsset: indexAsset)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PhotoGridViewModel.swift

```
class PhotoGridViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var index: [String:[IndexAsset]] = [:]
    @Published var indexAssets: QueryResults<IndexAsset>?
    @Published var sortedKeys : [String] = []
        
    func createIndex() {
        guard let assets = self.indexAssets else {return}
        self.createIndex(assets)
    }
    
    func createIndex(_ queryResults: QueryResults<IndexAsset>) -> [String:[IndexAsset]]? {
        indexAssets = queryResults
        if queryResults.count > 0 {
            var lastDate = Date.distantFuture
            
            var newIndex = [String:[IndexAsset]]()
            
            for i in 0..<queryResults.count {
                let item = queryResults[i]
                let isSameDay = isSameDay(firstDate: lastDate, secondDate: item.creationDate!)
                if isSameDay {
                    newIndex[item.creationDateKey!]?.append(item)
                } else {
                    newIndex[item.creationDateKey!] = [item]
                }
                lastDate = item.creationDate!
            }
            self.index = newIndex
            self.sortedKeys = newIndex.keys.sorted().reversed()
            return newIndex
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    private func isSameDay(firstDate:Date, secondDate:Date) -> Bool {
        return Calendar.current.isDate(
            firstDate,
            equalTo: secondDate,
            toGranularity: .day
        )
    }
 }
```

(I didn't include `Query` because it's long, and it's in the [post](https://davedelong.com/blog/2021/04/03/core-data-and-swiftui/) linked above. But also: the TLDR is that it stores the latest fetch results from Core Data, and when they change, it updates the `View` like a `@State` variable.)

Thanks y'all

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the view model object (we don't use those in SwiftUI) and use `@FetchRequest` for Core data which makes the View struct behave like an object.

You also need to remove the `id: \.self` because that crashes the `ForEach` `View`, you need to supply a unique identifier key on the data not the data itself.

Move the indexing into your Core Data model. And update it when you make a change.